# How much and for how long can I read from channels once selector returns?

Tags: java, sockets, udp, real-time, nio

Let's say I have some UDP channels and some TCP channels registered with my selector. Once the selector wakes up, can I just keep looping and reading as much information as I can from ALL keys (not just the selected ones) without looping back and performing another select()? For TCP this does not make much sense since I can read as much as possible into my ByteBuffer with a call to channel.read(), but for UDP you can only read one packet at a time with a call to channel.receive(). So how many packets do I read? Do you see a problem with just keep reading (not just reading, but writing, connecting and accepting, in other words ALL key operations) until there is nothing else to do then I perform the select again? That way a UDP channel would not starve the other channels. You would process *all channels* as much as you can, reading one packet at a time from the UDP channels. I am particularly concerned about:

1) Performance hit of doing too many selects if I can just keep processing my keys without it.

2) Does the select() do anything fundamental that I cannot bypass in order to keep reading/writing/accepting/connecting?

Again, keep in mind that I will be processing all keys and not just the ones selected. If there is nothing to do for a key (no data) I just do nothing and continue to the next key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to try it both ways. You can construct a plausible argument that says you should read every readable channel until read() returns zero, or that you should process one event per channel and do just one read each time. I probably favour the first but I can remember when I didn't.

> Again, keep in mind that I will be processing all keys and not just
>   the ones selected.

Why? You should process the events on the selected channels, and you might then want to perform timeout processing on the non-selected channels. I wouldn't conflate the two things, they are quite different. Don't forget to remove keys from the `selectedKeys` set whichever way you do it.

Comment: I think I have to loop through ALL keys because in the meanwhile some non-selected keys may become selected, you know what i mean? (like data may arrive for a key that was not selected) So I need to include them in my "outside-the-selector" loop. Looping without going through the selector.select() method looks weird but it also seems faster. I am just curious to know whether not calling select will actually cause any problems in the network level.

Comment: @JohnPristine All it will do is cause to you spin-lock the CPU, unless you do finally call it when you got a loop iteration where there was no I/O.

Comment: Yeah, only loop again if you read something. Otherwise go to the selector.select().